# Visual Studio VB.Net Showing Nothing For Object

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am having a really weird issue with visual studio. I was wondering if anyone else had encountered it as its doing my head in.

Basically when i debug through the code it sometimes shows an object which has been successfully initialised as being Nothing, even though i can open it up and look at its initialised properties (see below)

[image]

What on earth is happening here. Plz plz plz help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that `ReasonItemLookup` overrides `ToString` to return (say) the `ID` field - so if that's `Nothing`, that's what you'll see in the summary side of things.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet suggests, the string that is displayed in the debugger is the result of a call to ToString() on the object. So depending on the override of ToString, yes you can get Nothing for a non-null object.